# Automatically Execute a command when opening a new Integrated Terminal in VSCode IDE

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can VSCode IDE do this?
Execute a command such as running a batch file or powershell script automatically when a new Integrated Terminal is opened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous answer was deprecated although it will still work but with a warning.  The new way to do it in VS Code is to add this section to your settings.json.  Here I configured my PowerShell to automatically import a module posh-git that prettifies my command prompt for git.  :)

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {

    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell",
        "args": [
            "-NoExit", "-Command", "Import-Module posh-git"
        ]
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
        "source": "Git Bash"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs"` setting to pass arguments to the shell. For instance, the following will print `Hello World` when opening a new Terminal instance:

```json
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "-NoExit", "-Command", "Write-Host Hello World"
]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on the current version of VSCode

Comment: Hm... this still works fine here in 1.23.1, assuming that a) you're on Windows b) you didn't change `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` to something other than the default (PowerShell).

Comment: @Urasquirrel it have to work , but this is for win8 and10 because they use powershell, in win 7 vscode use cmd, so use cmd commands. read about it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_shell-arguments)